# I can't upgrade the GitLab 15.2.2 version to any further version, including 15.2.3, 15.2.5, 15.3.5 or 15.4.6. report a config JSON fail

Tags: gitlab, upgrade

I can't upgrade the GitLab 15.2.2 version to any further version, including 15.2.3,15.2.5,15.3.5 or 15.4.6. All report a config JSON fail. Anyone know how to solve? Thanks in advance.

I tried 15.2.3,15.2.5,15.3.5 or 15.4.6.

I think if it can be upgraded to 15.2.5, should be resolved.